# How can i retrieve a connectionString from a web.config file?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, web-config, connection-string

I am writing an client application in C# which will be supposed to change ConnectionString settings in a web.config file from another application I wrote.
How can I achieve this goal?

Is there a way to load the web.config file in my application and read/change its data object orientated? Or do I need to parse it as if beeing a complete 'unknown' XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing this from another application, you can use the [VirtualDirectoryMapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.virtualdirectorymapping.aspx) class:

```
VirtualDirectoryMapping vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(@"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\YourApplication", true);
WebConfigurationFileMap wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);


// Get the connectionString
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");
string connection = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use RMI to query the other application for the ConnectionString.

Comment: No, I meant RMI (Remote Method Invocation). I guess it's called .Net Remoting these days and now is lumped in with the whole WCF stack.